# TPU USB Accelerator to Coral Board

Tags: tensorflow-lite, tpu, google-coral

I am facing a problem of connecting TPU USB accelerator to Coral Dev Board. I follow the instruction in [here](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/multiple-edgetpu/#using-the-tensorflow-lite-python-api) but there is no success. I have tried to look for the port and this is the result on terminal screen:

[image: usb port:]

I have tried with different numbers for the index, but no help.

```
experimental_delegates=[load_delegate('libedgetpu.so.1', {"device": "usb:1"}
```

I found the tutorial demo on edge TPU and seems like the way they used to load the model is by the engine that just need to receive the path: https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/blob/c48c88871fd3d2e10d298126cd6a08b88d22496c/edgetpu/basic/basic_engine.py#L90

By looking edgetpu_utils: I have found my path for the TPU USB Accelerator is at `/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1`. But it still fails to load for some reason `RuntimeError: Error in device opening (/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1)!`

PLEASE HELPPPPP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is plugging the Accelerator through a Hub which is attached to the dev board instead of plugging it directly to the dev board.
Then the `load_delegate` should operate correctly